# I'm confused whether we can access the contents of list by not mentioning the index of elements in the code. Can someone explain this?

Tags: python

My tutor hasn't bothered to explicitly specify the index number to gain access to particular elements of a list. This seems strange to me and I believe it also affects the readability of code. Can someone explain how my tutor's code is working perfectly? I get the logic though.

***This is my code:-***

```
score_student = input("Enter the score of each student: ")
list_of_marks = []
list_of_marks = score_student.split(" ")
print(list_of_marks)
index_count = 0
for item in range(1, len(list_of_marks)):
    if list_of_marks[index_count] < list_of_marks[item]:
        index_count = item
    else:
        continue
print("Largest score in class = " + list_of_marks[index_count])
```

***Code of my tutor:-***

```
student_scores = input("Input a list of student scores ").split()
for n in range(0, len(student_scores)):
  student_scores[n] = int(student_scores[n])
print(student_scores)
highest_score = 0
for score in student_score:
     if score > highest_score:
          highest_score = score
print(f"Highest score in class:{highest_score} ")
```

Comment: In Python, we typically avoid iterating over indices, instead we iterate directly over the elements of all kinds of iterable objects. That's what your tutor is doing here. Iterating over elements means the same code will work regardless of the type of data structure you're iterating over, whereas code using indices is restricted to things that work with indices.

Comment: So you have this list - `scores = [100, 80, 90]` you could do - `for s in scores: ...` right? As long as the DS is an `iterable` - like `list` or `tuple` or even dict...

Comment: @DanielHao Exactly.

Comment: You can do `highest_score=max(student_score)` and let Python do the hard work.

Comment: You don't need that line `list_of_marks = []`. You redefine the list just below.

Comment: Are you sure your tutor knows Python to a level appropriate for teaching it as a subject ?

Comment: @AlbertWinestein The tutor might be trying to teach how one might implement max rather than using it first. For all you know, max is in a future lesson.

Comment: @joanis For all you know it might not be

Comment: @AlbertWinestein You're right, but I like to give people the benefit of the doubt when I have no indications either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### The explanation

In Python, we typically avoid iterating over indices, instead we iterate directly over the elements of all kinds of iterable objects. That's what your tutor is doing here.

Iterating over elements means the same code will work regardless of the type of data structure you're iterating over, whereas code using indices is restricted to things that work with indices.

##### Sample data structures with and without indices

These data structures support both iteration and integer indices, so your code would work too:

- lists
- tuples
- strings (iterating over the characters)

These data structures support iteration but not integer indices:

- sets
- dicts*
- generators

That's just a short list of examples, but there are many more.

##### When you also need indices, use enumerate

Sometimes in your code you might need the indices too, as well as the items you're iterating over. It might be tempting to go back to your original `for i in range(1, len(my_list)):` but it's better not to, because you would bring back the restriction that `my_list` actually has to support indices. The preferred solution in Python for that requirement is to use `enumerate()`:

```
for i, item in enumerate(something_iterable):
    # do stuff with item, knowing that it was in position i during iteration
```

##### Iterating over dicts

Dicts got a star is my list of iterables, because iterating over dicts is more complicated, since they contain key/value pairs, not simple items.

I think it's out of scope of your question to go into details here, but have a look at https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python/ for a decent presentation of that topic, or just Google "iterate over dicts in Python" for many more good pages covering the topic.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this beautiful explanation! So it's a good practice to avoid using indices while using any kind of loop statements so that it's functioning isn't restricted to DS that have index to locate the element. From now on, I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: Hey, you're most welcome. You'll find as you learn Python that the "Pythonic" way of doing things (yes, that's an expression you'll hear very often) is often quite different from the natural way to do the same thing in other languages. Python frustrated me quite a bit until I decided to invest in a course to learn it well, which has been really worth my while.